# Hide secret server code called from Meteor Methods

Tags: javascript, meteor, require

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to **hide secret server code from a client in Meteor Methods**. [The docs seem to imply](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#using-require) that the following is a general pattern of how it's done.
https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#using-require

(Note that, as per the docs, I'm using `require` instead of import, since `import` cannot be used in a conditional block.)

First, here's a Method defined in a file called `methods.js` and imported both on the client and the server:

```
/* methods.js */

let ServerCode
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  ServerCode = require('/imports/server-code.js')
}

Meteor.Methods({
  'myMethodName': function() {
    // ... common code
    if (Meteor.isServer) {
      ServerCode.secretFunction()
    }
    // ... common code
  }
})
```

Second, here's the secret server code in `/imports/server-code.js` which I am trying not to send to the client:

```
/* server-code.js */

class ServerCode {
  secretFunction() {
    console.log('TOP SECRET!!!!')
  }
}

const ServerCodeSingleton = new ServerCode()
module.exports = ServerCodeSingleton
```

*But* when I examine the source sent over to the client browser, I'm still seeing my secret server code being sent to the client:

[image: Screenshot of the server code being sent to the client]

Even when I do a production build, I can still search and find that 'TOP SECRET!!' string. I feel like I'm being too naive in my understanding of how `require` works, but the Meteor docs make it seem so simple. So what is the correct way to hide secret code that is called from Meteor Methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured this out I think.

The short version is, ignore what it says here; I believe it's incorrect or at least misleading:

https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#using-require

And follow what it says here instead:

https://guide.meteor.com/security.html#secret-code

A longer explanation is: In a *server-only file*, `import` the secret code **and assign it to a global variable.** Then, in a *common file*, use `isServer` (or `!isSimulation`) to conditionally refer to that global variable.

So my original example might be re-written like this:

```
/*   /imports/methods.js   */

// Note: no conditional use of require this time

Meteor.Methods({
  'myMethodName': function() {
    // ... common code
    if (Meteor.isServer) {
      ServerCode.secret() // <-- Defined as a global outside of this file!
    }
    // ... common code
  }
})
```

And so the **secret code** file might look like this:

```
/*   /imports/server-code.js   */

class _ServerCode {
  secret() {
    console.log("Shhhhhh, I'm secret()!")
  }
}
// Here's the global variable:
SecretCode = new _SecretCode()
```

And then in a **server-only** file it might look like this:

```
/*   /server/server-main.js   */

import '/imports/secret-code' // <-- declare the global
import '/imports/methods' // <-- use the global in here
```

And then in a **client-only** file it might look like so:

```
/*   /client/client-main.js   */ 

import '/imports/methods'

//...

Meteor.call('myMethodName')
```

Now the client and server can both execute ***some of*** the same exact code in the Method body (DRY), while some secret code can be server-only and won't get sent to the client as well. It's a little annoying to have to resort to using a global variable, but perhaps that's the cleanest option until a fancier version of `import` comes along that supports built-in lazy-loading of modules.

Comment: No need to create `Meteor.methods({/*...*/})` at "shared" (isomorphic) folders.  `Meteor.methods({/*...*/})` is executed only at server and must be placed under `server` directory, - with security concerns in mind

Comment: Read [`methods` docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html#Meteor-methods). Calling methods on the client defines __stub__ functions.

Comment: The docs do *not* say that Meteor.methods "must" be placed in a server folder. Stub functions, in this context, are not no-ops. They have immediate (though possibly temporary) side-effects which compensate for roundtrip latency. This is what Optimistic UI is all about. For example, in the To Do tutorial, a newly entered to-do item can appear immediately on the client before the server has even seen the insertion. After the server confirms the new item, or doesn't, the client resolves any discrepancies. At least this is my understanding.

Comment: "with security concerns in mind" - so you can place two methods with same name - one to the `server` directory with "secret" code and second to `client` directory with stub "latency compensation" code.

Comment: I'm not precisely sure what you are asserting in your last comment. But placing two similar methods with the same name in two separate places, which (due to optimistic UI) mostly do the same thing except for a little bit of secret code on the server, violates DRY principles. In other words, you're going to be maintaining similar code in two separate places. Check out that security link I included. It talks about my original question pretty much exactly. Here it is again: https://guide.meteor.com/security.html#secret-code

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: disregard answer, does not address OP's desire for DRY code or optimistic updates.

be default, Meteor implements an eager-loading scheme with regard to files. your methods.js is an example of that.

if a file is in a directory that's anywhere under a folder called "client", that file is served only to the client. likewise, any file under "server" is served only to the folder. so that's how you handle ensuring a file is served only to the server.

as you discovered, the "Meteor.isServer" construct only limits what's run in an environment, not what is served there.

i typically implement Meteor methods like this:

server/some/path/stuff.js:

```
// this is only on the server
Meteor.methods({
    'getStuff': function() {
        return "stuff";
    }
});
```

client/some/path/clientStuff.js:

```
// this is only on the client, calling the server method
Meteor.call('stuff', function(error, result) {
    if (error && error.reason) {
        alert(error.reason);
    }
    else {
        // use result
    }
});
```

regarding require, why are you using it?

i see that you have code in /imports, which Meteor treats as special and does not eagerly load. that tells me you're explicitly importing this stuff.

MDG has some strong recommendations for directory structure, ES15 modules and how to load code, which they detail here:

https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html

you'll note they don't use require, and are specifying modules differently from how you're doing it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I am aware of the recommended directory structure, but if you check out this link here: https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#using-require you'll see they mention require as a recommended option for when the module is being pulled in conditionally. ('import' is not allowed in a conditional block.)

Comment: Also, in the basic To Do tutorial (https://www.meteor.com/tutorials), the Meteor methods are imported on *both* the client and the server. This is how Optimistic UI behavior is made possible. The way you are implementing your Meteor methods would prevent Optimistic UI effects. Maybe Optimistic UI and secret server code are mutually exclusive, but I just don't understand why the docs would make it seem like they're not..

Comment: ah, i get what you're doing. i somehow missed your require statement the first time. ok, yes, reading the link you provided about require, it sure looks like it's supposed to work as you indicated. sorry i missed your actual question!

Comment: As far as I am aware the optimistic UI does not depend on including server methods on the client. That happens because you have minimongo on the client. If you do your inserts in a server method, then you lose it, but can't you do your inserts/updates on the client and keep your secret code on the server?

Comment: @Mikkel Well, what you're suggesting is not exactly wrong, but it is not considered best practices: it can violate DRY (you're writing the same code twice), and introduces security issues (client can do rogue writes). Meteor docs recommend disallowing direct write-operations on the client, and instead suggests Methods as a more secure approach. In other words, all DB write-operations should happen in the Method bodies, and Methods should be imported on both client and server. I actually just figured out the right way to do this, and am writing an answer.